# what is the best way to represent a char in its bits representation(Python)

Tags: python

I'm looking for the best way to represent a char in its bits representation **by a given number of length(a variable)**
For example:
in bytes representation, the number '5' is: 0101 if the given length is 4.

Comment: Did you mean `0101` instead of `1010`? And please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> print '{:04b}'.format(5)
0101
```

In the string '{:04b}', the "4" means that we want the result to include 4 characters even if fewer are required and the "0" means that we want it to pad the result with zeros.

If you want the size under program control:

```
>>> n = 6 ; '{0:0{1}b}'.format(5, n)
'000101'
```

Or:

```
>>> n = 6 ; ('{:0%sb}' % n).format(5)
'000101'
```

Or:

```
>>> n = 6 ; ('{:0' + str(n) + 'b}').format(5)
'000101'
```

Comment: but if '4' is a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) or [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with `04b` as [format specification](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> format(5, '04b')
'0101'
>>> '{:04b}'.format(5)
'0101'
```

You can also specify the length 4 as argument if you use `str.format`:

```
>>> '{:0{}b}'.format(5, 4)
'0101'
>>> '{0:0{1}b}'.format(5, 4)
'0101'
```